# AWS Cloudfront + http API gateway + mtls

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, mtls

we have an issue with implementing mTLS with cloudfront. We would like to route requests through cloudfront / WAF, to the api gateway custom origin using mTLS.

It looks like this use case is unsupported, wondering if there are any good workarounds or any other options we could use? We want to use cloudfront with the WAF, since WAF is not supported on the HTTP gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying ensure that all request go through Cloud Front you could inject a secret header and check it on the Http API with a lambda authorizer.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/restricting-access-http-api-gateway-lambda-authorizer/